# $x^T A x > 0 \forall x \neq 0$ for a symmetric matrix $A$ with eigen values $\lambda_i > 0 \ \forall i$

Tags: linear-algebra

I am trying to prove this property of PD matrices. Here is what I have:
A is symmetric.
$$A=U \Lambda U^T= \sum_{i=1}^n \lambda_i u_i u_i^T$$
$$x^T A x =\sum_{i=1}^n x^T \lambda_i u_i u_i^T x$$ $$=\sum_{i=1}^n \lambda_i \|u_i^T x\|_2^2$$
Now here I say that since $A$ is symmetric therefore $U$ is an orthonormal basis and hence $u_i \neq 0  \ \forall i$. Since $U$ is an orthonormal basis, if we pick $x$ st $u_i^T x = 0$ for some $i$, we have for some $j \neq i:$ $\|u_j^T x\| > 0$. Therefore, since $\lambda_i >0$, we have $x^T A x > 0$.

Are these arguments correct? I have skipped a few steps, so I can add those if it's not completely clear what I am trying to say.

Comment: $x^T A x > 0$  $\forall x \neq 0$ looks like the [definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Positive-definite_matrix) of $A$ being PD. What is your definition?

Comment: Oh sorry, I meant $\lambda_i > 0 \ \forall i$. I'll change the question.

Comment: It is OK, though the ending "if we pick $x$ st ..." is a bit obscure. Better: for every $x\ne 0$ there exists $i$ st $u_i^Tx\ne 0$ etc. Even better: denote $y=U^Tx$, clearly $x\ne 0$ iff $y\ne 0$ as $U$ invertible. Then $x^TAx=y^T\Lambda y=...$.

Comment: Ah, I was worried that the language I used was not too good for a proof. But I really like the second suggestion. Thanks!

Comment: @A.G. Were you planning on making that into an answer?

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Honestly I did not plan that, but if you insist I will make this formality.

Comment: @A.G. If you had answered no, I would just have made a quick CW post summarizing the comments

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your approach to do the unitary diagonalization of $A$ is sound. After you have got
$$
x^TAx=\sum_{i=1}^n \lambda_i \|u_i^T x\|_2^2
$$
it is only left to ensure that there is at least one term in the sum of squares that does not vanish for $x\ne 0$. If all terms are zero, i.e. $u_i^Tx=0$ for all $i$, then the vector $x$ is orthogonal to all basic vectors $u_i$, thus, to the whole space, which is possible only if $x=0$.

The same thing with matrix notations is a bit shorter: denote $y=U^Tx$. Since $U$ is invertible we have $x\ne 0$ $\Leftrightarrow$ $y\ne 0$ and, hence, for $x\ne 0$
$$
x^TAx=y^T\Lambda y=\sum_{i=1}^n\lambda_i\|y_i\|^2\ge\lambda_\min\|y\|^2>0
$$
which proves that $A$ is positive definite.